# Wrapping PropertyEdtior exceptions during Spring validation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

When I submit a Spring form and a PropertyEditor fails to convert a value, an exception is thrown and a message like this ends up in my validator errors object:

```
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type
org.joda.time.DateMidnight for property startDate; nested exception is
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2010-111" is malformed at "1"
```

Can I wrap this somehow, providing a friendlier message to display on screen?

I'm using @Valid in my controller, with the following in my form:

```
@NotNull
protected DateMidnight startDate;
```

Thanks

Comment: The trouble here is, that the property editor rejects the input way before the `@Valid` stuff is invoked, so the validation API is irrelevant. Not that this helps you any....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message has message codes such as `typeMismatch.objectName.startDate` (see [DefaultMessageCodesResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DefaultMessageCodesResolver.html)). To display a user-friendly message, you need to [declare a `MessageSource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-messagesource) with the corresponding messages.